# Есть ли библиотеки api для получения данных с разных сайтов

Tags: php, битрикс, rest

Есть интернет магазин на Битриксе. Возникла задача написать api, который бы могли использовать различные партнеры, для передачи своих заказов к нам в систему. У партнеров могут быть системы на самых разных cms/фреймворках. 
Не понимаю, как при создании заказа в системе партнеров он мог сразу же выгружаться к нам в систему.
Есть ли какие то готовые библиотеки/примеры api для решения таких задач или подскажите, вообще в каком направлении смотреть?

Простите за такой вопрос, сталкиваюсь с такой задачей в первый раз.

Comment: Вам нужно будет создать у себя на сайте API endpoint, на который, при создании заказа партнеры будут отправлять Вам информацию о заказе, и вы будете создавать у себя заказы

Comment: То есть, я у себя создаю url, куда партнеры будут передавать данные(к примеру json методом post),далее я их декодирую и дальше работаю с ними. Я правильно понял?

Comment: Да, абсолютно верно

Comment: Искреннее спасибо за ваш ответ, но не могли бы вы подсказать еше один момент: мне, в таком случае, надо будет разработать шаблон передачи данных для партнеров, чтобы ото всех данные поступали в одном формате. У меня нет информации, к примеру установлен ли у них cURL, или (тут уже я не знаю)как происходит передача данных с сервиса, написанным на java (такой как минимум 1 точно есть).Реально ли написать одну универсальную документацию для всех или лучше сделать одну, покрывающую большинство случаев, а для остальных, так сказать, "по запросу"?

Comment: вы пишите api функцию....вам не важно каким образом до вас дойдут эти данные...самое главное чтобы внутри данные соответствовали вашему формату (например `Json` или `Xml`). И после вы должны сделать документацию к этому Api, по которой ваши "клиенты" поймут как именно формировать пакеты данных и тыкать их вам.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Делаете у себя на сервере API метод

Type: POST

Url: '/api/v1/order'

Data Params: тут будут Ваши параметры в нужном Вам формате

Далее валидируете данные, и строите логику.

В документации опишите нужные Вам параметры, тип запроса и т д.

Вот и все